# Updating flow of code without affecting old users

Tags: swift

I have an app where I've created an onboarding for users. When they first join, I set them an `onboarding` value of 0. Then depending on the actions they take, the `onboarding` number is incremented until they're done with the onboarding.

Now I want to change up the flow of the onboarding to make it more intuitive. It works for new users because they're starting from `onboarding: 0`. However, users before the update that are in different stages of the onboarding (1, 2, etc) have a messed up process as the flow is different.

What do I do so old users are unaffected, and new users are put through the new flow?

Sample of the code:

```
switch onboardingStep {
case 0:
  //step 1
case 1:
  //step 2
case 2:
  //step 3
default:
  break
}
```

The new flow includes more steps, with some put in between the old ones. 
So far I've tried introducing another variable `newOnboardingStep` which runs separately to the `onboardingStep`, and shows different popups depending on the combination of the two. However, that's very messy and confusing. I'm sure there's a better way.

Any help welcome, I've been banging my head all day!

Answer (score 1):

Nothing says your ints actually have to be in order so take advantage of that fact.

In the old flow, when the user is done with step 2, they go to step 3. In the new flow have completing step 2 take the user to step 5, and completing step 5 takes them to step 3.

Answer (score 1):

Why not add a version number? Add it only if you also see that this user has not started the sequence. Then, those with no version number are assumed to be version 0 and they still get the old sequence. Those who have version 1 get the new sequence. And this approach will continue to work moving forward if you revise the sequence again.

Answer (score 1):

You should record the last used app version of each user and store it in `UserDefaults`. To determine whether this is an old user opening the app after an update, just check this condition:

```
lastUsedBuild != currentBuild && lastUsedBuild != 0
```

`lastUsedBuild` equalling 0 would mean this is a new user.

After you have determined whether the user is an old user opening the app for the first time after the update, you do the new onboarding if they are a new user, and if they are an old user opening the app for the first time after the updat, you should map the current step number to a  new step number. This can be done with a dictionary:

```
let stepMappings = [
   1: 1, // this means that originally people on step 1 will still be on step 1
   2: 3, // originally people on step 2 will be on step 3
   3: 4, // originally people on step 3 will be on step 4
   ... // you should decide which new step should the old user be on, for each old step
]
```

And then you can do:

```
onboardingStep = stepMappings[onboardingStep]!
```